# ¿Porque no me esta funcionado esta solucion?

Tags: java, array, string, matrices

tengo un problema con un codigo en java y es que tengo que transcribir un codigo de c++ a java y pues he estado mirando como hacerlo pero no doy con la solucion, mi problema original es este link: https://vjudge.net/problem/UVA-10646  , ya lo hice en c++ y funciona correctamente pero quiero hacerlo en java pero no conozco muy bien la sintaxis he estado intentado hacer esto:

codigo de c++:

```
#include <iostream>
 
int main() {
 int T;
 
 char cards[52][3];
 
 scanf("%d", &T);
 
 for (int t = 1; t <= T; ++t)
 {
 for (int i = 0; i < 52; ++i){
 scanf("%s", cards[i]);
 }
 printf("Case %d: %s\n", t, cards[32]);
 }
}
```

y este es mi intento de pasar el codigo anterior de c++ a java

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.Map.Entry;

public class concantenar {

    public static Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    static BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

        char matriz[][] = new char[52][3];
        int q =0;

        int n = sc.nextInt();

        for (int i = 1; i <= n; i++) {
            for (int x = 0; x < i; x++) {
                for (int y = 0; y < matriz[x].length; y++) {
                    matriz[x][y] = sc.next().charAt(0);
                }
            }
            q++;
            System.out.println("Case " + q + ":" +matriz[32]);
        }
    }
}
```

asi deberia ser la entrada y la salida, en el link del enunciado puedes encontrar el problema

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

pero la salida me la muestra asi en java, ¿Que puedo hacer?

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Si alguien me ayudara en resolver esto estaria muy agradecido, gracias :D

Comment: si matriz es un array, porque imprimis un solo valor en java?

Comment: matriz es una matriz lo imprimo  asi: matriz[32] porque asi es en c++ y creo que tambien se puede en java ?, o es diferente?

Comment: Si no pudieras.. tiraria error... ahora, las matrices en C++ no tienen nada, pero nada que ver con las matrices en ningun otro lenguaje.. y las formas de imprimirlas tampoco... que es lo que querias imprimir ahi? toda una fila????

Comment: Para imprimir un valor de una matriz (arreglo bidimensional) en java tienes que indicar los 2 índices

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Según veo tu código de c++:

1 Ejecuta el ingreso de datos, tantas veces como el usuario así lo requiera.

2 Al ejecutarse almacena 52 datos

3 Te devuelve el dato en la posición de cards[32] el cual es "8H".

En java no necesitas usar un arreglo bidimensional para aplicar la misma función

```
int T;
  T=sc.nextInt();
  char cards[]=new char[52];

  for (int t=1;t<=T ;++t ) {
      for (int i=0;i<52;++i ) {
          cards[i]=sc.next().charAt(0);
      }
  
 System.out.println("caso "+t+": "+cards[32]);
}
```

Comment: si tienes razon amigo, gracias por tu ayuda, exactamente eso era lo que necesita